# How to change NSScroller length

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nsscroller

Is there any api to change the `scroller` length,  I would like to do the same without subclassing `NSScroller`.

Comment: You mean -setKnobProportion: method?

Answer (score 1):

NSScroller (as a subclass of NSView) has a setFrame: method that takes an NSRect. Pass in the appropriate width or height to set the length of your control.

Comment: This doesn't work if the NSScrollView / WebView is layer-backed. In this case, the custom frame you set is being ignored. Any ideas how to fix this? :)